# How to create DbContext

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

below default code in controller working fine

```
public ProductController(appDbContext parmContext)
{
    _context = parmContext;
}
```

now I want to add DAL and in that, getting error creating object of type appDbContext, what to pass/set for parmContext?

below is the connection in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddDbContext<appDbContext>(config => 
    {
        config.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PreSales"));
});
}
```

Below is the code I want to use

```
public IEnumerable<ProductStatusMaster> GetProductStatusFRdal()

    // here I ant to create object of DBcontext (i.e. _context)

    {
        try
            {
                 var msm = _context.ProductStatusMaster
                    .Where(s => s.ActiveYn == 1 )
                    .OrderBy(s => s.Status)
                    .ToList();

                return msm;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
    }
```

Comment: You should use DI in your Controller like MyAppController(hisodContext context)  { _context = context; ... } or manually resolve dependency in your method via serviceprovider.

Comment: plz share reference site if you know any. - thx

I don't have issue in the controller code

Comment: https://medium.com/volosoft/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-best-practices-tips-tricks-c6e9c67f9d96  for example.  https://hackernoon.com/asp-net-core-how-to-use-dependency-injection-in-entity-framework-core-4388fc5c148b   also will help you

Comment: getting
No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Comment: @M Singh, Did you inherit your appDbContext from DbContext? Did you create a migration for your appDbContext?

Comment: Yes

public IEnumerable<ProductStatusMaster> GetProductStatusFRdal()


     appDbContext  _context = new appDbContext();


    {
        try
            {
                 var msm = _context.ProductStatusMaster
                    .Where(s => s.ActiveYn == 1 )
                    .OrderBy(s => s.Status)
                    .ToList();

                return msm;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
    }

Comment: Your code so strange - firstly you register dependency with AddDbContext, after that in your code create new appDbContext instance which not connected with any one by current "new" call instead of using code like this: private IServiceProvider _provider;  public MyAppController(IServiceProvider provider)
{  _provider = provider; }      IEnumerable<ProductStatusMaster> GetProductStatusFRdal() appDbContext _context = provider.GetService<appDbContext>(); { try { var msm = _context.ProductStatusMaster .Where(s => s.ActiveYn == 1 ) .OrderBy(s => s.Status) .ToList(); return msm; } catch { throw;}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me get an answer.

There are 2 ways to realize code you want.
1) Through Controller DI.
2) Through Service Locator pattern (antipattern).

By the code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddDbContext<appDbContext>(config => 
    {
        config.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PreSales"));
});
}
```

you set up dependency for DbContext and configure connection parameters. So, for the first method you should pass the dependency through controller. Possible code will be like this:

```
public class MyTestAppController
{
     private appDbContext _context;

     public MyTestApController(appDbContext externalAppDbContext)
     {
         _context = externalAppDbContext;
     }

     public IEnumerable<ProductStatusMaster> GetProductStatusFRdal()
     {
        try
            {
                 var msm = _context.ProductStatusMaster
                    .Where(s => s.ActiveYn == 1 )
                    .OrderBy(s => s.Status)
                    .ToList();

                return msm;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
    }
}
```

2) Using Service Locator pattern

In this case you should use IServiceProvider dependency. Code example like this:

```
public class MyTestAppController
{
   private IServiceProvider _provider; 

   public MyTestAppController(IServiceProvider provider) => _provider = provider; 

   public IEnumerable<ProductStatusMaster> GetProductStatusFRdal() 
   {
      var _context = _provider.GetService<appDbContext>(); 

      try 
      { 
           var msm = _context.ProductStatusMaster .Where(s => s.ActiveYn == 1 ) 
                     .OrderBy(s => s.Status) .ToList(); return msm; 
      } 
      catch { throw; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, tried #2 but I believe its still failing.